# How to run some check based on the previous status of an instance before that it is stored in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instance

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to run some check based on the *previous* status of an `@article` instance before that it is stored in the database. That is, I have to run some method that make use of data already stored in the database related to `@article` (in the below case that data is `{:id => 1, :title => "Sample title", :content => "Sample content", :status => "private"}` and *not* `{:id => 1, :title => "Sample title changed!", :content => "Sample content", :status => "private"}`).

I thought to proceed "retrieving"/"re-building" the original instance after that its attribute values have changed. That is:

```
# In the controller file

# @article.attributes
# => {:id => 1, :title => "Sample title", :content => "Sample content", :status => "private"}
@article.update_attributes(params[:article])
# => {:id => 1, :title => "Sample title changed!", :content => "Sample content", :status => "private"}


# In the model file
before_save :retrieve_original

def retrieve_original
  # self.attributes
  # => {:id => 1, :title => "Sample title changed!", :content => "Sample content", :status => "private"}

  original = ... # ?
  # original.id
  # => nil
  # original.attributes
  # => {:title => "Sample title", :content => "Sample content", :status => "private"}
  # self.attributes
  # => {:id => 1, :title => "Sample title changed!", :content => "Sample content", :status => "private"}
end
```

So, `original` should be an `Article` object *and* just a duplicate of the `@article` instance (without the `id` and without that `@article` attributes have changed).

I tried to play with some Ruby on Rails method (like `ActiveRecord::Base.dup` or `ActiveModel::Dirty.changed_attributes`), but I have not found a solution. Furthermore, I think that *there's a better way to accomplish what I would like to make compared to my approach.* **If so, what I might do?**

---

I would like to do that because, for example, if an article is public it should be not possible to change the title value; if the article is private, it should be possible to change the title value. Of course, I have to make that check before to store the edited article data and for all attempts that try to update that data (for this I chose to use a `before_save` callback). However, if the user try to change the title value and the private value to public, then all checks run in a public "context", but I would like that those checks still run in a private "context" since the previous status was private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can go through the [changes](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html#M000291) hash in your hook. I.e. `dup` or `clone` the changed version, then go through changed version's `changes` and set the attributes back to what they were for your copy.

Comment: Is it possible to make that in a easy/clear way (for example, without to use blocks)?

Comment: Yes, blocks are not needed. `old_title, new_title = @article.changes['title']` should do the trick.

Comment: @Mark Thomas - Assuming the approach I try to use in the question is right, I need an instance variable with attributes properly set and not simply attribute values.

Comment: using a block is probably easiest, doing something like `original = clone; changes.each { |attr, changed_attrs| original.send("#{attr}=", changed_attrs[0] }`

Answer (score 0):

just save

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])`
@orginal = @article
if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
  @original.do_some_method_that_probably_should_be_a_before_update
  #.... whatever is next .....
end
```

Or rethink why  you need to do what you think you need to do.

Comment: As wrote in the updated question, I would like to run checks for all attempts that try to update the `@article` data (for this I chose to use a `before_save` callback).

Comment: what does run checks mean exactly? I can guess, but what do you want to check for and why?

Comment: I wrote that at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You could just grey out the title in the view and not bother checking on update, too.

Comment: People (with some hacking) are still able to submit data related to the `title`.

Comment: it's yagni i'm afraid. Make it work, ship it, repeat. And if it's an issue, use `attr_accessible` on this model.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. Basically, instead of trying to revert the changes afterwords and checking then, it would be easier to make a copy of the object before changes are made.

One way to do this is to create a new object from the 'attributes' of the current object like this:

```
tmp_article = @article.attributes
```

Do this before you make any changes to the model object. Then before you save you can use the hash `.diff` method that's built-in to rails:

```
diff_hash = tmp_article - @article.attributes
# diff will now contain any differences. It will be empty if they are identical.
```

Here's a link to the diff extension in Rails:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/diff.rb